# notify users when changed database

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, database, jquery

I want to be notified when a meta from the database changes.
In fact, I built a chat system with Ajax and currently this Ajax is executed every 2 seconds and if there is a new message, it displays it.
I don't want Ajax request to be sent every 2 seconds.
Is there a way to send me a notification only if the database changes in a certain meta?

Comment: you mean push notifications? That requires your server to run something that has a constantly long running program such as a Node server that can open and maintain a websocket, WP/PHP applications are ran on demand and are loaded from scratch on each request, otherwise polling is your only option. It's also much easier to trigger a push event from your chat AJAX code than it is to watch the database. "Watching" the database would mean polling it regularly

Comment: Can you guide me further?
I use WordPress hosting

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the resources to write out that kind of answer as it's quite involved and requires a lot of non-WordPress technical expertise, and depends enormously on your personal preference of programming language and budget for hosting. I mentioned Node.js as it's a popular choice, but even within Node.js there are lots of competing options and hosting options, none of which are PHP or WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want Ajax request to be sent every 2 seconds. Is there a way to send me a notification only if the database changes in a certain meta?

**You can't watch the database for changes like this.** The most you could do is add filters on post meta changes on the PHP side to trigger an event.

The problem is that you would then need to send that data to the browser, and the only way to do that with PHP is polling. **Polling is unavoidable if you are going to use only PHP.**

To get a continuous connection that allows you to *push* the event to the user unprompted, you need a websocket, and that is not something you can implement in PHP with WordPress. You will need to explore non-PHP alternatives to implement your chat server/livechat.

Of note, WordPress.com uses websockets for live comment updating and notification updates, however in order to do this, their PHP sends a ping to a separate service that runs in Node.js which can run websockets. Note that all of the options require additional hosting requirements that go beyond the standard PHP+MySQL of a WordPress site.

Livechat and chatrooms have their own storage and coding requirements that don't fit so well with WordPress tables such as post meta.